# Как сделать (полями/методами) класса названия таблиц в базе данных, к которой подключился?

Tags: ооп, php_pdo, php, pdo

Я пользуюсь PDO, не знаю чем это может помочь в данной ситуации, но все же. В общем реально ли сделать такое:

Имена таблиц подключенной базы данных должны стать (полями/методами), и иметь свои методы (поля). А по факту это просто цепочка методов выходит.

Напр. (допустим мы подключились к бд test и в ней есть таблица Users)

```
$m = new MDB();

$m->Users()->GetRec($a);
```

Comment: fetchobject

Comment: у меня тоже на этом мысль заканчивается.